# How to read links with id and write in output file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, beautifulsoup

I am trying to write csv file with url and id as in input file but I am not getting idea.

I have below format csv file:

```
ID              Links
P51800010436    https://maharerait.mahaonline.gov.in/PrintPreview/PrintPreview/UHJvamVjdElEPTcxNzkmRGl2aXNpb249NiZVc2VySUQ9MzQ5MjAmUm9sZUlEPTEmQXBwSUQ9NzUzNjYmQWN0aW9uPVNFQVJDSCZDaGFyYWN0ZXJEPTI2JkV4dEFwcElEPQ%3d%3d
P51800001202    https://maharerait.mahaonline.gov.in/PrintPreview/PrintPreview/UHJvamVjdElEPTMxOTcmRGl2aXNpb249NiZVc2VySUQ9MjU5MjQmUm9sZUlEPTEmQXBwSUQ9MjM3MzQmQWN0aW9uPVNFQVJDSCZDaGFyYWN0ZXJEPTk3JkV4dEFwcElEPQ%3d%3d
P51800000150    https://maharerait.mahaonline.gov.in/PrintPreview/PrintPreview/UHJvamVjdElEPTY1NSZEaXZpc2lvbj02JlVzZXJJRD03MjU3JlJvbGVJRD0xJkFwcElEPTExOTY2JkFjdGlvbj1TRUFSQ0gmQ2hhcmFjdGVyRD04MSZFeHRBcHBJRD0%3d
P51800001785    https://maharerait.mahaonline.gov.in/PrintPreview/PrintPreview/UHJvamVjdElEPTU2NjUmRGl2aXNpb249NiZVc2VySUQ9MjgxODEmUm9sZUlEPTEmQXBwSUQ9MjY4NjcmQWN0aW9uPVNFQVJDSCZDaGFyYWN0ZXJEPTIxJkV4dEFwcElEPQ%3d%3d
```

The script I have tried:

```
from datetime import datetime
start_time = datetime.now()

from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import requests
import re

import csv

link = []
rera_id = []

with open('D:/TF_Vishnu/link_with_rera_id.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')

    for row in reader:
        rera_id.append(row[0])
        link.append(row[1])

for index, rera_id, url in enumerate(rera_id, link):

    df_url = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(url), header=None)

    df_rera_id = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(rera_id), header=None)

    html=requests.get(url).content

    soup=BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

    if (soup.find(text="Other Than Individual") == "Other Than Individual"): 

        print ("Processing Other Than Individual Link.......")

        table = soup.find_all("table",{"class":"table table-bordered table-responsive table-striped"})[1]

        df_2 = pd.concat([df_rera_id, df_url, df, df_1], axis=1)

        df_2.to_csv('D:/scrape_data/test.csv', index=False, header=False, mode='a'))
```

I want to write csv file using pandas as way like first column - rera_id, second - link, third - data, .... so on.

Please help and suggest something. Apologies for any mistake

Getting Error:

TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: Do you have a header line? If yes, you have to ignore it.
Furthermore I am a bit confused by your definition of `df_url` and `df_rera_id`. There you specify it to be yet another csv files. This seems wrong to me.
The list error you gave might be in the non-shown code (`# did something`).

Hope this few hints help you.

Comment: getting error here: `for index, rera_id, url in enumerate(rera_id, link):

TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your usage of `enumerate` builtin. The second (optional) parameter is not treated as some another iterable object, but as the initial value of the enumerating variable (`index` in your case) - that's why it expects and integer. You should better try enumerating the `reader` directly:

```
with open('D:/TF_Vishnu/link_with_rera_id.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    for index, (rera_id, url) in enumerate(reader):
        # Your code below
```

Hope it helps!